# What means Unmerged into origin/master in magit?

Tags: magit, git

In the magit buffer I see `Unmerged into origin/master`, yet I'm not noticing see any issues while merging with magit or with git on the commandline.

Searching for the the subject brought me here[0], yet I don't understand it's meaning.

Maybe someone can shed some light here for me.

[0] https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Getting-Started.html

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, that message means that you have commits in your local repository that hasn't been pushed in the remote repository. If you push your commits in the local repository, then you get away of that message.

After reading your question, I created a commit in my dotfiles repository and I got that messaage (see image below).

[image]

After pushing the commits (i.e. pressing `p u`) to the remote repository, that message disappeared (see image below).

[image]

Note that in my remote repository, the most significant branch is `main`, that's why the message shows `origin/main` instead of `origin/master`.